# Ionic slidebox inside tabs

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm having trouble getting a slidebox to work with the ionic framework.

I used the tabs seed project, changed some code and just inserted the demo code from the documentation for a slide-box.

Here is a plunker of the app:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FxRyJ62sCtSiJdGUPzAz?p=preview

The slide-box is in the data tab (tab-data.html).

It looks like everything works right: The directive is recognized etc. but the slide-box does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. Just that the slide-box is very small.
Add a

```
 style="margin:100px 0px;text-align:center;"
```

to the `<h1>` and you'll see, it works.